# How can i unit test a Kstream with an Kafka Binder?

Tags: spring, junit, apache-kafka, apache-kafka-streams, spring-cloud-stream

i want to unit test an Kafka Stream Aggregate and i am  totally confused which method to use.
I read about the TestSupportBinder but i do not think this is working in my case, therefore i use the KafkaEmbedded Method. This is  how i initialize the embedded Kafka.

```
 @Before
public void setUp() throws Exception{

Map<String, Object> consumerProps = KafkaTestUtils.consumerProps("group-id", "false", embeddedKafka);

consumerProps.put(ConsumerConfig.AUTO_OFFSET_RESET_CONFIG, "earliest");
consumerProps.put(ConsumerConfig.KEY_DESERIALIZER_CLASS_CONFIG, StringDeserializer.class);
consumerProps.put(ConsumerConfig.VALUE_DESERIALIZER_CLASS_CONFIG, StringDeserializer.class);

DefaultKafkaConsumerFactory<Object, LoggerMessage> cf = new DefaultKafkaConsumerFactory<>(consumerProps);
consumer = cf.createConsumer();
embeddedKafka.consumeFromAnEmbeddedTopic(consumer, OUTPUT_TOPIC);
}
```

What i want to test is the following:

```
public interface Channels {
  String LOGGER_IN_STREAM = "logger-topic-in-stream";
  String LOGGER_IN = "logger-topic-in";
  String LOGGERDATAVALIDATED_OUT = "loggerDataValidated-topic-out";

  @Input(Channels.LOGGER_IN)
  SubscribableChannel processMessage();

  @Input(Channels.LOGGER_IN_STREAM)
  KStream<Object, LoggerMessage> loggerKstreamIn();

  @Output(Channels.LOGGERDATAVALIDATED_OUT)
  MessageChannel validateLoggerData();
}
```

And i get following error message

> org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'some.domain.Channels': Invocation of init method failed; nested exception is java.lang.IllegalStateException: No factory found for binding target type: org.apache.kafka.streams.kstream.KStream among registered factories: channelFactory,messageSourceFactory
>
> Caused by: java.lang.IllegalStateException: No factory found for binding target type: org.apache.kafka.streams.kstream.KStream among registered factories: channelFactory,messageSourceFactory

What am i doing wrong?

Comment: Is Kafka Streams binder on the class path? If you can share a small sample project on Github, we can take a look.

Comment: Yes kafka Streams binder is on the classpath in version 2.0.1.Release. Overall i am using springbootVersion 2.0.6. I can not share a sample project, i would have to alter almost everthying. Any more clues where i can start to look?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I missed to inject my Channels Interface as a MockBean. After i did that everything worked as expected.